# Hardware won't respond to each others ARP requests

Tags: ip, tcp, ethernet, arp

I have two pieces of hardware (embedded devices) that I have setup to communicate via TCP over Ethernet in a client/server fashion.

The topology of the network is as follows:

```
-----
| S ||=|== Debug PC (w/ Wireshark) 192.168.10.41
| W ||=|== Hardware 1 TCP Client 192.168.10.42
| I ||=|== Hardware 2 TCP Server 192.168.10.40
| T |
| C |
| H |
-----
```

When Hardware 1 try's to send packets to the server, Hardware 2, it sends out an ARP packet to get Hardware 2's MAC address first:

```
No.     Time        Source             Destination  Protocol Length Info
157 11772.776136 Microchi_13:c3:6a     Broadcast    ARP      60     Who has 192.168.10.40?  Tell 192.168.10.42
```

However, it receives no reply from the server, and then the server ARPs for the clients MAC a few moments later:

```
No.     Time        Source             Destination  Protocol Length Info
158 12183.800839 00:3f:2d:02:1a:35     Broadcast    ARP      60     Who has 192.168.10.42?  Tell 192.168.10.40
```

Which also receives no reply from the client. I am very confused.

I know that the Server is replying correctly, since I wrote a simple TCP Client in C# that could connect and send packets to the server from the Debug PC.

I'm not sure why my Hardware Client cannot communicate.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Details of ARP packets if needed:**

From Client:

```
Ethernet II, Src: Microchi_13:c3:6a (00:04:a3:13:c3:6a), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: Microchi_13:c3:6a (00:04:a3:13:c3:6a)
    Type: ARP (0x0806)
    Trailer: 000000000000000000000000000000000000
Address Resolution Protocol (request)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (1)
    Protocol type: IP (0x0800)
    Hardware size: 6
    Protocol size: 4
    Opcode: request (1)
    [Is gratuitous: False]
    Sender MAC address: Microchi_13:c3:6a (00:04:a3:13:c3:6a)
    Sender IP address: 192.168.10.42 (192.168.10.42)
    Target MAC address: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Target IP address: 192.168.10.40 (192.168.10.40)
```

From Server:

```
Frame 158: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: 00:3f:2d:02:1a:35 (00:3f:2d:02:1a:35), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: 00:3f:2d:02:1a:35 (00:3f:2d:02:1a:35)
    Type: ARP (0x0806)
    Trailer: 000000000000000000000000000000000000
Address Resolution Protocol (request)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (1)
    Protocol type: IP (0x0800)
    Hardware size: 6
    Protocol size: 4
    Opcode: request (1)
    [Is gratuitous: False]
    Sender MAC address: 00:3f:2d:02:1a:35 (00:3f:2d:02:1a:35)
    Sender IP address: 192.168.10.40 (192.168.10.40)
    Target MAC address: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
    Target IP address: 192.168.10.42 (192.168.10.42)
```

Comment: What is the netmask in your case? Do you have any static routes defined in your device's configuration aside from the default route? BTW: you would not see any ARP replies as these are going unicast to the destination hosts - your switch does filter unicast packets to foreign destinations for your "debug PC". You could use a hub instead or enable the "monitor" or "mirror port" feature on your switch (if available) to get all traffic flooded to "debug PC's" port.

Comment: @syneticon-dj The netmask in this case is just: 255.255.255.0. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by static routes, but I have not added anything extra and just used default TCP settings.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I didnt know ARP replies were unicast. That is why I wasn't seeing any response. But in fact is was connecting fine. You can add an answer and I will accept it if you like.

Comment: I've expanded the text somewhat for better readability and inserted some reference links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not see any ARP replies on your "debug PC" switch port as [these are going unicast to the destination hosts](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html). Your switch is filtering unicast packets to foreign destinations for your "debug PC". If you need to monitor unicast traffic as well, you could either use a hub instead of a switch or enable the ["monitor" or "mirror port" feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) on your switch (most managed switches do have something like this) to get all traffic including foreign unicasts flooded to "debug PC's" port.